# Ace Editor hide last sumbols by vertical scrollbar

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I'm using the editor Ace. It works fine, but when the text exceeds the width of the editor, there is a vertical strip that covers the last two characters. How to fix it?

Comment: This sounds like a bug, but might be triggered by options you use could you create a demo to show the issue?

Comment: http://shard0.azurewebsites.net/ Enter "#calc(2^(1/3);)" to condition end click run. It hide ">" subol at the end, in FF. In IE it hide two last sumbols.

Answer (score 1):

maxLines option doesn't work well when there is a horizontal scrollbar which creates a vertical one https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/2336
the code at https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.8/lib/ace/virtual_renderer.js#L924 needs to be updated to account for the scrollbar too.

Answer (score 1):

you need: editor.renderer.setScrollMargin(12, 12, 0, 0); (top, bottom, left, right)